# Square plot in a meshgrid in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot multiple squares of size `1x1` using `meshgrid`. The current and expected outputs are presented.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.array([0,1,2])
Y = np.array([0, -1, -2])
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
plt.plot(xx, yy,"s")
plt.show()
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Comment: you should be looking for line collection, not `plot`.

Comment: The style `"s"` is for square bullet not for tracing grid. If you aim to draw squares you need to provide coordinate of them in right order using  [Patches](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html) or tracing vertical and horizontal lines using `axhline` and `axvline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to suggest the following solution. Given the assumption that we have 1x1 squares, `meshgrid` is not necessary:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

X = np.array([0, 1, 2])
Y = np.array([0, -1, -2])

x_sorted = np.sort(X)
y_sorted = np.sort(Y)

ax.set_xticks(x_sorted)
ax.set_yticks(y_sorted)

ax.set_xlim(x_sorted[0], x_sorted[-1])
ax.set_ylim(y_sorted[0], y_sorted[-1])

ax.grid()

ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')

plt.show()
```

[image]